# Async Await not behaving as expected

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to do a function in my node server that uses cheerio to **scrape** a web, the problem is for some reason my functions are not behaving as intended,

Controller:

```
class ScraperController {
    static async scrapeDwelling(req, res, next) {
        try {
            const dwelling = await ScraperService.getDwelling(req.params.url);
            console.log(dwelling);
            res.send({dwelling});
        } catch (err) {
            next(err);
        }
    }
}
```

then my service:

```
static async getDwelling(url) {
    const dwelling = {};
    await request(`https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/${url}`, (err, resp, html) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        dwelling.type = $('.price-operation', '#article-container').text();
        dwelling.price = $('.price-items', '#article-container').text();
        dwelling.description = $('.section-description', '#article-container').text();
        dwelling.title = $('.title-type-sup > b').text();
        dwelling.location = $('.title-location > b').text();
        const coordinatesHelper = ($('.static-map', '#article-map').attr('src'));
        const coordinates = coordinatesHelper.substring(
            coordinatesHelper.lastIndexOf('markers=') + 8,
            coordinatesHelper.lastIndexOf('&channel')
        );
        dwelling.coordinates = coordinates;
        console.log($('#tab-foto-flickity').find('img').length);
        return dwelling;
    });
    return dwelling;
}
```

as you see the console logs for some reason the function is returning first then executing the code. i get this in the console:

{}

GET /public-api/scraper/42998731.html 200 6.559 ms - 15

36

Answer (score 4):

The `request` node module doesn't return a promise, it uses a callback function. You could either manually wrap your request in a Promise like this:

```
static getDwelling(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(`https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/${url}`, (err, resp, html) => {
            if(err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(html);
        });
    }).then((html) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const dwelling = {};
        dwelling.type = $('.price-operation', '#article-container').text();
        dwelling.price = $('.price-items', '#article-container').text();
        dwelling.description = $('.section-description', '#article-container').text();
        dwelling.title = $('.title-type-sup > b').text();
        dwelling.location = $('.title-location > b').text();
        const coordinatesHelper = ($('.static-map', '#article-map').attr('src'));
        const coordinates = coordinatesHelper.substring(
            coordinatesHelper.lastIndexOf('markers=') + 8,
            coordinatesHelper.lastIndexOf('&channel')
        );
        dwelling.coordinates = coordinates;
        console.log($('#tab-foto-flickity').find('img').length);
        return dwelling;
    });
}
```

Or you could use a library like [request-promise-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise-native).

Comment: It would be much better to do `resolve([resp, html]);` right away and then do `.then(([resp, html]) => {` with the `cheerio.load(html);` and such, so that if any of the rest of the logic throws, the promise will reject properly instead of throwing an uncaught exception. Generally you want the size of a `new Promise` block to be as small as possible.